# Verbal analogy: sweet _ness_ is to suffix as boat _swain_ is to ... In other words, what is the term for the _swain_ morpheme?

Tags: linguistics, morphology

At some point in the past I encountered the following verbal analogy:

SWEET ***NESS*** : SUFFIX :: BOAT ***SWAIN*** : ?

---

In my view, the question is asking what one would term the "swain" morpheme in "boatswain".

I have ruled out *suffix* itself as "swain" is neither an inflectional nor (appears to be) a derivational ending.

Some answers I have found and excluded are:

- *suprafix*/*superfix* : this pertains to the patterns of tone or stress on various parts of a word that may determine its meaning, e.g. to distinguish between the verb form of *conduct* from the noun form
- *stem* : would only work if you considered "boat" as a prefix

My best guess so far would be "root", in that the word "boatswain" consists of two roots -- "boat" and "swain" -- in a similar way to the word "wheelchair".

---

What do the expert linguists among you think?

Comment: *Sailors* turned "boat" and "swain" into "boatswain" (and then "bosun"), just as they have been responsible for the creation of many other words in English.

Comment: That is basically the definition of a compound: it consists of two (or more) roots. So yes, _root_ works. Or _element_, or _part_. (Would this question not be a better fit for [linguistics.se]? The word happens to be English, but the process of compounding is a cross-linguistic one.)

Comment: Without looking anything up, I would say that 'boat' is a prefix to 'swain', that being a term for someone in charge of something.  As for instance a 'coxswain'.

Comment: I wonder if *swain* by itself is considered archaic enough or obsolete that *-swain* in *boatswain*, *coxswain*, etc could be considered a [cranberry morpheme](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cranberry_morpheme)?

Comment: @HotLicks One sometimes sees bosun written *bo'sun* for that reason. I cannot find on the internet an abbreviation for *coxswain*, however.I am sure that in Norfolk they say *cox'sun*  *The Cromer lifeboat has a new cox'sun*. People certainly say *coxsun*.

Comment: @WS2 - Yeah, there are at least 4 different ways to spell *boatswain*.

Comment: @DanBron - that's a great answer. I think we can safely say that the meaning of the word "swain" (rustic youth, or male admirer) is very different to the meaning it has as a word ending (leader).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - I also wasn't sure the question belonged on the site. Then I saw the "linguistics" tag, so decided to ask.

Comment: As you think, like 'boat' it's a **free morpheme** as 'swain' is still listed by major dictionaries, with the original sense or close enough of 'boy' (Old Norse sveinn "boy"). That's if it is still considered sensible to treat 'boatswain' as a compound ('bosun' would prove problematic).

Answer (score 2):

I believe the correct term is a **bound root**.  This refers to the part of a compound word that is not (or is no longer) an independent word.

According to [SIL](http://www-01.sil.org/linguistics/glossaryoflinguisticterms/WhatIsABoundRoot.htm):

> A bound root is a root which cannot occur as a separate word apart
>   from any other morpheme.

Comment: _Swain_ is listed in major dictionaries.

Comment: Granted, though it is often marked as archaic, and is certainly not a part of common English parlance.

Comment: Collins, AHDEL, M-W and RHK Webster's do not flag it as such. Macmillan flags it as 'literary'. ODO is the only dictionary I've found using a bare 'archaic' label. And even archaic words are still words.

Comment: @Sawbones - I can see your point that the independent word has only a tenuous connection with the morpheme. However, as others have pointed out, "swain" does not adhere to the strict definition of "bound root". I will try to ask better questions in future. +1 Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of canoodling around on the intertubes with the google leads me to believe that the answer is

> SWEET *NESS* : SUFFIX :: BOAT *SWAIN* : **STEM**

The second syllable of "sweetness" modifies the first syllable, turning the adjective into a noun, but it's the first syllable of "boatswain" that modifies the second, turning "swain" (a young man) into a particular type of young man, namely one who works on a boat.  Thus the correspondence is a semantic one between the roots "sweet" and "swain," which appear in different syllabic positions in their containing words. It might be tempting to make the correspondence a syllabic one based on the order of the syllables, and conclude that both second syllables are suffixes, but that's incorrect.

Comment: +1 I think this might be the official answer to the analogy. By analogy with words such as "wheelchair", I suspect that the stem might be the entire word "boatswain".